# How to decompress Gzip data in azure stream analytics?

Tags: azure, stream, compression, gzip, analytics

We are using IOT hub for receiving data from IP enabled devices, as the data is growing we wanted to compress in ip enabled device and send it to iot hub. we are using Azure stream analytics for processing telemetry messages. according to microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#configure-an-iot-hub-as-a-data-stream-input) we can use Gzip stream to decompress and get the data back.

in stream analytics we have used below settings
Event compression type: Gzip
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/easVA.png)

we are trying below code to compress:

```
string fltext = File.ReadAllText("input_new.txt");
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fltext);
            Console.WriteLine("Before Converting message:" + buffer.Length);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (var zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true))
            {
                zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            var compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);

            var gzBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 0, compressed.Length);




            var fullyConverted =  Convert.ToBase64String(gzBuffer);

            Console.WriteLine("Before Converting message:" + gzBuffer.Length);

            var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceSpecificConnection);

            var message = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message(gzBuffer);


            deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, gzBuffer.Length);
            Task.Delay(5000);
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Do mind that you are using an incorrect async/await pattern as you are not awaing your tasks, like `deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);` and `Task.Delay(5000);` There might be errors that will go unnoticed.

Comment: No, we are able to send messages to iot successfully. we read messages using device explorer from iot. same message we received. sending part is success. we struck with decompress only after sending message to iot Azure stream analytics should decompress and produce output to blob or somewhere, it is not happening. we did't see any errors also. Thanks in advance.